# "prob. evaluating classifier: rand" in LibSVM, WEKA

Tags: weka, svm, libsvm

I installed WEKA and downloaded wlsvm, added the jars, libsvm.jar and wlsvm.jar to CLASSPATH thus, succesfully integrated LibSVM into Weka Environment.
I generated random numeric attributes (features) and categorical -of course- classes and tried run LibSVM but I got this error "problem evaluating classifier: rand".
I have no idea why I got this error, I looked it up on the internet and didn't end up with any solution. would you please help me?
By the way, I am so new to WEKA, Java and LibSVM.

Comment: is there a specific reason why you're using such an exotic setup?

Comment: Actually, LibSVM is only way to do SVM. Is there any other simple way that I am not aware of?

Comment: New versions of WEKA (for example 3.7.7 which can be downloaded from http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) has a package manager. With package manager you can download and integrate libsvm to WEKA automatically. Package manager is accesible through WEKA GUI Chooser -> Tools menu.

Comment: ok, I downloaded Weka 3.6, which is Stable book 3rd ed. version. now, I removed it all and will install developer's version. I will tell the results. Much obliged!

Comment: I am using Weka 3-6-8 on OSX and I don't have a package manager to install libsvm.  I am running it via the .app (so not command line) and I am getting this same error (after I've moved libsvm.jar and updating Info.plist) and now I get this error and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The best solution is to integrate LibSVM to MATLAB and not to use Weka. You can use commands of LibSVM (e.g. svmtrain or svmpredict) or you can find the codes online.

Comment: Hkn's tip works for me. But it took me 2 days until I discover the way. The answer: You need to manually download the ZIP file of the latest version of the libSVM "plugin" and manually set the local  (already downloaded) installation file on top-right (unnoficial File/URL) corner of the Package Manager window.

Comment: Did anyone find a proper solution for the `rand` problem? I'm stuck with the same issue and found this question, but I think no one really answered it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) is a great library. However, in my experience the best, most up to date and most tested version of LIBSVM is the normal, C++ version of LIBSVM. I would suggest you try downloading and testing the random data you generated in the normal LIBSVM. This doesn't even involve C++ coding all you have to do is generate a training file and a testing file in the LIBSVM input format.

Doing so will allow you to more effectively troubleshoot what is going on. If it doesn't work with the C++ version, then we can definitely check that, if it does work with the C++ version we can be sure that the problem is the (1) interaction with WEKA, (2) an old bug in LIBSVM java that has not been fixed, (3) what you call wlsvm.jar (which I'm not sure what it is) or a mixture of these things.

Comment: for more information wlsvm.jar, check http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~yasser/wlsvm/
Anyway, so, your suggestion is to use normal libsvm, which uses run/execute command. I will try that, I will tell the results

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you update to a 3.7 version of weka.
I had the same problem as you (also noticed it lead to the kind of error using the
visualization tool).
I downloaded weka 3.7.8, then used the package manager to install libsvm, and since then
it works.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too,if i dont guess it wrong ,such exception has been throw:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: rand
    java.lang.Class.getField(Unknown Source)
    weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM.buildClassifier(LibSVM.java:1618)
    weka.gui.explorer.ClassifierPanel$16.run(ClassifierPanel.java:1409)
```

so it seems your libsvm version is too low and some filed has been changed.